# Wubi for Win 8 and UEFI bios

Tags: 13.04

When will Canonical come out with a version of Ubuntu for Win 8 and UEFI? 
I really don't want to create a new partition. A Wubi version would be fine.

Comment: This may never happen: http://askubuntu.com/questions/280667/will-i-be-able-to-use-wubi-to-install-ubuntu-releases-newer-than-12-10

Answer (score 0):

[Wubi doesn't work on UEFI systems](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/694242) that use GPT disks. Every new computer with Windows 8 has a UEFI boot, because that's the only thing that supports secure boot. It works fine with Windows 8 if you boot with BIOS.

**There's no practical workaround at this time**, other than waiting for a fix from Canonical's Ubuntu installer team. The amount of effort required to switch to a legacy BIOS boot and replacing the GPT disk with a MBR partition table setup would negate the whole point of Wubi: to easily install and remove Ubuntu from Windows (for trial purposes).

Anyway, Wubi support was officially dropped since 13.04 and is no longer an supported install option for Ubuntu: [Intention to drop Wubi from 13.04 release](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-April/036993.html).