# ubuntu 13.04 offline install with wubi

Tags: 13.04, .desktop

I downloaded wubi and "ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso" and kep in same folder.When i initiated install wubi starts to download 12.X. version of ubuntu and never considered downloaded **ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso**.Help me how can i install U13.04 using  wubi [offline].

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/280667/will-i-be-able-to-use-wubi-to-install-ubuntu-releases-newer-than-12-10

Answer (score 0):

Mount the ISO file and on it is it's own wubi installer. Use that.