# Installation - wubi.exe does nothing

Tags: installation

I downloaded the Iso for v13.04. I mounted it and tried to execute wubi.exe but nothing happens. Tried both 32bit and 64 version. Tried to run it with anti-virus turned off but I don't even get an error message.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/280667/will-i-be-able-to-use-wubi-to-install-ubuntu-releases-newer-than-12-10

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu dropped Wubi-support since 13.04. You can't use it for 13.04 or newer. I suggest you to use 12.10 or 12.04 LTS.

Comment: I'll try. But how else can you install 13.04 then? (wubi was the only installer included in the iso file)

Comment: @Melv: Please follow these installation http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest instructions to install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same problem when my hdd was about to crash..  So check ur hdd health.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend expanding this to explain *how* to do this.