# I can´t install Ubuntu using USB

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows-7, usb-creator

I tried to install Ubuntu 13.04, downloaded from this site, I use a Universal USB Installer to create my bootable USB, when I boot and follow the steps until the one that says "Your Lap has currently installed Windows 7, what do you want to do?" I choose the option "INstall Ubuntu inside {OS}"(it says literaly "inside {OS}") and click CONTINUE, my laptop restarts and the process begin since step 1. I try and try many times, but it always happens. What can I do? 
If I choose the option "Something else", it shows that my Hard Disk is already partitioned, and appear thing like: dev/sda...ntsf...
A few days ago I installed Ubuntu in Virtual Box, but it ran very slowly, so I decided install it by this.
My Lap is Samsung,
Windows 7
Intel core i3

Hope you can help me.

Comment: *How* exactly are you installing? What steps do you take, starting from when you download Ubuntu and up to when you see that option? Are you *booting* from the USB flash drive or CD/DVD to see that option? It seems like the option that appear in a Wubi installation. See [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu), [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular installation?](http://askubuntu.com/q/615/22949), and [Will I be able to use wubi to install Ubuntu releases newer than 12.10?](http://askubuntu.com/q/280667/22949)

Comment: I downloaded UBUNTU 13.04 32bits, from this site, then I used program Universal USB Installer, to save this image ISO in my USB.

Comment: I boot from my USB and follow the steps, (Try Ubuntu or Install Ubuntu) i chose Install Ubuntu, then I connect to my Wi-fi, and the next step is to choose between "Install Ubuntu inside {OS}, or delete this SO and install ubuntu, or something else.

Comment: Does the message say "Install Ubuntu inside Windows" or does it say some other operating system (or does it actually say "{OS}")? Is Windows your other OS? It's fine to say "Windows" here. :) Also, can you confirm that it says *inside* and not *alongside*? (Please edit your question to provide all this information, as well as what you've already commented--that way, someone reading the question will know what's going on, and also some or all of our comments can be deleted. Thanks!)

Comment: So I choose the option Install Ubuntu inside {OS}, but inmediatly I click continue, my Lap restarts. ANd if I choose something else, i can watch that my Hard Disk is alredy partitioned, and appear 4 things like that: dev/sda... ntsf, etc

Comment: It doesn't says "Install Ubuntu inside Windows" it says "install Ubuntu inside {OS}" literaly, but the instruction says: "This machine has currently installed Windows 7, what do you want to do?

Comment: Interesting. Does [the ISO image's MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) check out? And if so, if you press Shift while booting the USB flash drive and use the up and down arrow keys and Enter key [to select "Check disc for defects"](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html) (this applies to USB installation media as well as actual CD/DVD discs), are any errors found?

Comment: “Inside” is another problem. There should be “beside”. Are you sure you can have an extra _primary partition_ to install Ubuntu? And can you choose “Something else” **without doing anything else** and just make a screenshot from the partition table?

Comment: It's not "inside" man, it's "alongside". I've never seen an option to install "inside". It looks like this, right: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xaQ3N.png? Except, you say yours says "{OS}" instead of "Windows", right? Anyways, can you please do the following: boot the USB, but choose "Try Ubuntu" instead. When it opens up, click on the "Dash" icon (top icon on the left bar) and search GParted. Open that application, take a screenshot of it, upload it to http://www.imgur.com, and give us the link.